# Anyway to keep format on CurrentItem:Body when using Send Email workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to use the SP2010 Workflow action -> Send Email and have the [%Current Item:Body%] keep the format/layout of the content? Right now I have the return field as: Plain Text and I created a post with bulleted list and it did not show in the Send Mail action workflow. Possible without coding?

Answer (score 1):

the problem si that sharepoint use RTF fields to store HTML text. When you use this text in sharepoint it si rendered ad HTML and you see it in a nicer format. Unfortunatly spd could not render RTF text, you shound use it as plain  text